# ASA 5505 mac address allocation issue

Tags: cisco, asa

I have a ASA 5505 in transparent mode with a Security plus licence

```
Licensed features for this platform:
Maximum Physical Interfaces       : 8              perpetual
VLANs                             : 20             DMZ Unrestricted
Dual ISPs                         : Enabled        perpetual
VLAN Trunk Ports                  : 8              perpetual
Inside Hosts                      : Unlimited      perpetual
Failover                          : Active/Standby perpetual
Encryption-DES                    : Enabled        perpetual
Encryption-3DES-AES               : Enabled        perpetual
AnyConnect Premium Peers          : 25             perpetual
AnyConnect Essentials             : 25             perpetual
Other VPN Peers                   : 25             perpetual
Total VPN Peers                   : 25             perpetual
Shared License                    : Enabled        perpetual
AnyConnect for Mobile             : Enabled        perpetual
AnyConnect for Cisco VPN Phone    : Enabled        perpetual
Advanced Endpoint Assessment      : Enabled        perpetual
UC Phone Proxy Sessions           : 2              perpetual
Total UC Proxy Sessions           : 2              perpetual
Botnet Traffic Filter             : Enabled        perpetual
Intercompany Media Engine         : Disabled       perpetual
Cluster                           : Disabled       perpetual
```

Whilst attempting to edit a vlan with the command: `int vlan 7`
I receive back `ERROR: % Cannot allocate MAC address to interface`

Is this related to the error message in the ASDM when clicking add new interface i receive the error message "You cannot have more than 3 vlans in your system"? And if so why do i get this message?

```
ASA Version 9.1(6)8
!
firewall transparent
!
interface Ethernet0/0
switchport access vlan 2
!
interface Ethernet0/1
!
interface Ethernet0/2
switchport access vlan 3
shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/3
switchport access vlan 4
shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/4
switchport access vlan 5
shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/5
switchport access vlan 6
shutdown
!
interface Ethernet0/6
switchport access vlan 7
!
interface Ethernet0/7
switchport access vlan 8
!
interface Vlan1
description Management Pc Connection
nameif inside
bridge-group 1
security-level 100
!
interface Vlan2
description Dead End - No Connection
nameif outside
bridge-group 1
security-level 0
!
interface Vlan8
description Management Pc Connection
nameif ManPc-HpILO
bridge-group 4
security-level 100
!
interface BVI1
description ASA Management Bridge Group
ip address 
!
interface BVI3
description Vmware Bridge Group
ip address 
!
interface BVI4
description HP ILO 4 Bridge Group
ip address 
!
ftp mode passive
pager lines 24
mtu outside 1500
mtu inside 1500
mtu ManPc-HpILO 1500
no failover
icmp unreachable rate-limit 1 burst-size 1
no asdm history enable
arp timeout 14400
no arp permit-nonconnected
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:00:30
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat     0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy
user-identity default-domain LOCAL
http server enable
http inside
http 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 inside
no snmp-server location
no snmp-server contact
snmp-server enable traps snmp authentication linkup linkdown coldstart     warmstart
crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto ca trustpool policy
telnet timeout 5
no ssh stricthostkeycheck
ssh timeout 5
ssh key-exchange group dh-group1-sha1
console timeout 0
threat-detection basic-threat
threat-detection statistics access-list
no threat-detection statistics tcp-intercept
!
class-map inspection_default
match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
parameters
message-length maximum client auto
message-length maximum 512
policy-map global_policy
class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map
  inspect ftp
  inspect h323 h225
  inspect h323 ras
  inspect rsh
  inspect rtsp
  inspect esmtp
  inspect sqlnet
  inspect skinny
  inspect sunrpc
  inspect xdmcp
  inspect sip
  inspect netbios
  inspect tftp
  inspect ip-options
!
service-policy global_policy global
prompt hostname context
no call-home reporting anonymous
Cryptochecksum:e02cea00fefdea428cbbd8994f237335
: end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware that transparent mode does not quite share the licence allowance.

According to Cisco,

Security Plus License + Transparent Mode
 3 active VLANs
(2 active VLANs in 1 bridge group, plus 1 active VLAN for failover)